# How can I keep the first key in the JSON without replacing the new one?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**Main.py**

```
import json

def test(key, value):
    with open("test.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        x = json.load(f)

        num = 1

        try:
            if f"q{num}" in x["keys"]: # Checking if index 1 is exist
                for _ in range(num):
                    num += 1
        except:
            pass

        x["keys"] = {}
        x["keys"][f"{num}"] = {"key": key, "value": value} # Dict for json file
        
        with open("test.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            json.dump(x, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False) # Write the json file


test("test", "testvalue")
test("test2", "testvalue2")
```

**test.json**

```
{
    "keys": {
        "1": {
            "key": "test2",
            "value": "testvalue2"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I keep the first question without replacing the second one? I wanted to make it like this (If it possible):

```
{
    "keys": {
        "1": {
            "key": "test",
            "value": "testvalue"
        },

        "2": {
            "key": "test2",
            "value": "testvalue2"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if its really possible to make it like this. If its not possible to do this, please let me know!

Comment: What is that `q` doing in `f"q{num}"`? Looks like your problem is just a typo? There's a bunch of code in your example that doesn't really need to be there, and it seems odd that you're not just using the '"key"' as a key, but it appears this is your current issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. It checks whether you can actually load the file as json (since that will fail with an empty file), then finds the maximum key value in the `keys` dict and adds a new entry with an incremented key.

```py
import json

def test(key, value):
    with open("test.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        try:
            x = json.load(f)
            next_key = max(map(int, x['keys'].keys())) + 1
        except:
            # empty file
            x = { 'keys' : {} }
            next_key = 1
    
    # add the new value
    x['keys'].update({ next_key : { 'key' : key, 'value' : value } })
    
    # write the new data
    with open("test.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(x, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Contents of `test.json` after running:

```
test("test", "testvalue")
test("test2", "testvalue2")
```

will be:

```json
{
    "keys": {
        "1": {
            "key": "test",
            "value": "testvalue"
        },
        "2": {
            "key": "test2",
            "value": "testvalue2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above is a very solid answer.  I would have used `setdefault` instead of the try / except but ymmv.

Comment: @2ps Thanks. The try/except is also to catch an exception on attempting to `json.load` an empty/invalid file. I figured as long as I had to do to that, I may as well use the same block to catch a missing key error as well.